# Why would SSHing to a server gives me REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED, but my known_hosts file and the server have not changed?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, osx-mavericks, osx-el-capitan

Putting this here in the attempt to help others who may run into this obscure problem.

I recently upgraded OSX from Mavericks to El Capitan.  I then attempted to log into a system I had previously logged in to, and ssh threw this error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:Btm9/3heWnRLKNiuhw4efh6sQWqCr/dNJUD87ejdR6k.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:33
ECDSA host key for real.hostname.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I looked in my known hosts file and see the public key:

```
real.hostname.com,192.168.0.138 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDHxFq6UNxndgThogOpKGYHK0HpmK1niGPBdNVyo9Q8zX//ms3joRH+tvL0RigJ+i5f0qSUjK2j80BYyCjnCXkYJ+YIPOGioGiuFGuoFutvJLH4iXT652b2WxJJwPqAvz70Xez1ToFxsIl8H0noUNTmlXRsfY0G5gX+089aghq3hH8OGUIGoyGCrv7Dpdh+tiMDXQqz0R4yhOa0iAojv+SVqbzArT8/AxC8VzuNDww6Fi96rxK1vaFg9SJEegwAZzWcbUFopA4cb8r7sQ5tHG56L5zX9/Yadg4/Pf02O6dP62M1rW7x6VoG/gEa72axqV/izm7/ws7SASsiKtHKRijf
```

I then went to another machine, verified the key above matched that in the known_hosts file of the other machine.  I then connected from that other machine to real.hostname.com without any errors or warnings.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is the upgrade from Mavericks to El Capitan.  It turns out that the ssh client has been upgraded in El Capitan, so when it attempts to connect to a ssh server, it now uses a different key type instead of "ssh-rsa".

In this case ssh attempts to use "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256".  On a newer system, if you run "ssh-keyscan" on the domain, it will spit out both the ssh-rsa key type  and ecdsa-sha2-nistp256:

```
myname@myhost-1:~$ ssh-keyscan real.hostname.com
# real.hostname.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
real.hostname.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 k8DaAFOzRyv0kbP8Ua48IIk8DaAFOzRyvAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBAOq0InBTTdCqbaackF5biy0QghSFZBV/MRoL936yOAXgPAnZlHl+zQ5weK7nM2UNt2qGxqWKLSZ6gE6slZnQkw=
# real.hostname.com SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
real.hostname.com ssh-rsa k8DaAFOzRyv0kbP8Ua48IIk8DaAFOzRyvk8DaAFOzRyv0kbP8Ua48IIk8DaAFOzRyvFq6UNxndgThogOpKGYHK0HpmK1niGPBdNVyo9Q8zX//ms3joRH+tvL0RigJ+i5f0qSUjK2j80BYyCjnCXkYJ+k8DaAFOzRyv0kbP8Ua48IIiXT652b2WxJJwPqAvz70Xez1ToFxsIl8H0noUNTmlXRsfY0G5gX+HGXoLuLsr9VEghX2oyGCrv7Dpdh+tiMDXQqz0R4yhOa0iAojv+SVqbzArT8/AxC8VzuNDww6Fi96rxK1vaFg9SJEegwAZzWcbUFopA4cb8r7sQ5tHG56L5zX9/Yadg4/Pf02O6dP62M1rW7x6VoG/gEa72axqV/izm7/ws7SASsiKtHKRijf
```

When the newer version of ssh attempts to match the ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 key-type string to the ssh-rsa key-type string it fails, rather than recognizing that they're two different key types for the same machine.

I consider this a bug, but I have no idea where I'd post it.